# How to change the current theme in prestashop 1.7?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need help in changing my current default theme in Prestashop 1.7. I have manually uploaded my preferred theme into the themes folder but it is not detected in the dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

With Prestashop 1.7 & new theme system, you must have a configuration file named `theme.yml` in a `config` folder into your theme folder like this: 
[image: theme folder]

Without this file, your theme doesn't appear into your BO.

Here, you have the config content file documentation: http://developers.prestashop.com/themes/gettingstarted/index.html#theme-yml

Here, you have the FO theme documentation: http://developers.prestashop.com/themes/index.html?highlight=theme